# django queryset orm - from same table fetch data in particular format

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I am having my models.py is something like this

```
CHOICES = (
    (1,'Test1'),
    (2,'Test2'),
    (3,'Test3'),
    (4,'Test4'),
    (5,'Test5'),                
)
class A(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField('A', max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.x

class B(models.Model):
    emp = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='emp')
    y = models.ForeignKey(A, verbose_name='a')
    z = models.IntegerField('testing', choices = CHOICES)
```

I have some data inside these tables in database.

1. User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)

   ```
   [u'user1', u'user2', u'user3']
   ```
2. A.objects.values_list('x', flat=True)

   ```
    [u'python', u'java', u'php', u'javascript']
   ```
3. B.objects.values_list('emp__username', 'y__x', 'z')

   ```
   [(user1', u'python', 3L), (user2', u'php', 5L), (u'user1', u'javascript', 5L), (u'user3', u'python', 5L), (u'user3', u'java', 5L)]
   ```

I want output something like this

```
employees = {
    'user1':{
           'Test5':"javascript",
           'Test4': "",
           'Test3':"python",
           'Test2':"",
           'Test1':""
         },
    'user2':{
           'Test5':"php",
           'Test4': "",
           'Test3':"",
           'Test2':"",
           'Test1':""
          },
    'user3':{
           'Test5':"python, java",
           'Test4': "",
           'Test3':"",
           'Test2':"",
           'Test1':""
          },
  }
```

I can do it but with multiple database calls. Can we achieve the same with minimum queryset / database calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is simple:

```
bs = B.objects.select_related('emp', 'y').order_by('emp__username', 'z')
```

These `B` instances have all the information you need. For a start you could do:

```
from itertools import groupby
user_dct = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(bs, lambda b: b.emp.username)}
user_dct
{'user1': [b1, b2], 'user2': [b3], 'user3': [b4, b5]}
```

and go from there...

Comment: Thank You. That's the one I was looking for. :)